# Dropping rows in Python using != operator is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to drop rows in my dataset using:

```
totes = df3.loc[(df3['Reporting Date'] != '18/08/2017') & (df3['Business Line'] != 'Bondy')]
```

However it is not what I expect; I know that the number of rows I want ot drop is 496 after using:

```
totes = df3.loc[(df3['Reporting Date'] == '18/08/2017') & (df3['Business Line'] == 'Bondy')]
```

When I run my drop function, it is giving back much less rows than my dataset minus 496.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are u sure you should be using &. Maybe you meant "and" & is a bitwise and operator.

Comment: You can't just negate the components of a conjunction to negate the conjunction. (See de Morgan's laws.)

Comment: @HongyuWang: `&` is correct. `and` isn't overloadable, so libraries like NumPy and Pandas overload `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to use `&`, but it is being misused. This is a logic problem. Note:

```
(NOT X) AND (NOT Y) != NOT(X AND Y)
```

Instead, you can calculate the negative of a Boolean condition via the `~` operator:

```
totes = df3.loc[~((df3['Reporting Date'] == '18/08/2017') & (df3['Business Line'] == 'Bondy'))]
```

Those parentheses and masks can get confusing, so you can write this more clearly:

```
m1 = df3['Reporting Date'].eq('18/08/2017')
m2 = df3['Business Line'].eq('Bondy')

totes = df3.loc[~(m1 & m2)]
```

Alternatively, note that:

```
NOT(X & Y) == NOT(X) | NOT(Y)
```

So you can use:

```
m1 = df3['Reporting Date'].ne('18/08/2017')
m2 = df3['Business Line'].ne('Bondy')

totes = df3.loc[m1 | m2]
```

Comment: Presumably a slightly more direct approach (with fewer parentheses) would be to use their original `!=` query, just replace `&` with `|`, making it `totes = df3.loc[(df3['Reporting Date'] != '18/08/2017') | (df3['Business Line'] != 'Bondy')]`. That's just distributing the "not"/`~`, and it reads cleanly as "keep the stuff where the reporting date isn't the bad date *or* the business line isn't Bondy". I'm assuming `pandas` overloaded `|` to mean `or` the same way it overloaded `&` to mean `and`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Good point. Basically: `NOT(X & Y) == NOT(X) | NOT(Y)`.